# Valid ng-src syntax for string concatenation inside directive template string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an ng-src attribute within an image tag that is loaded as a string from the template property of a directive, which supposed to load an image selected by the user. However when the page loads, the console outputs a 404 since there is no image selected and ng-src is loading an empty image. What I currently have is this

```
"<img  ng-src="myserver.com/{{imagesPath+ selectedImage}}"></img>"
```

but whenever `selectedImage` is an empty string I get the empty request.

What I tried changing it to was

```
"<img class='snapshot' ng-src='{{selectedImage.length? \'myserver.com\' + imagesPath +selectedImage : \'\' }}'></img>"
```

And this does not work. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, using the ng-if solved it (Thanks for that!!). Although I had to change the way that the string is concatenated inside the ng-src:

```
ng-src="{{'myserver.com/'+ imagesPath}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check `selectedImage.length> 0`, so that whenever there is selected image found it will create an `src` path

```
"<img class='snapshot' ng-src='{{selectedImage.length> 0 ? \'myserver.com\' + imagesPath +selectedImage : \'\' }}'/>"
```

Better way would be hide that `img` tag from html  when there is no image using `ng-if` directive.

```
"<img ng-if="selectedImage.length > 0" ng-src="myserver.com/{{imagesPath+ selectedImage}}"/>"
```

Comment: @Alan does it helped?